# What is the springfox in the pom dependency?

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

what is the springfox.
i saw in the pom.xml properties.
but i can't understand the springfox.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

like above, i don't understand what it means and how exactly it works.
I searched about it but there's no information what springfox is.

Comment: http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/

Comment: Somehow missed the [tag:springfox] which would answer the question if you read the tag excerpt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SpringFox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/) is an automated API documentation generator for API's built with Spring-Mvc or Spring Boot. The latest released version as of this posting is `2.4.0`